# Recall translations made with Poedit

Tags: theme-development, multi-language, language

I designed a WordPress theme from scratch starting from my html site and in the conversion I used the functions `_e()` and `__()` to make the theme multilingual ready.

Then I created the translation .po and .mo files via Poedit (containing translations of the texts concerned) and enabled translation support via `functions.php`. So in theory I should have all the elements at my disposal.

So my question is simple: is there a way to recall translations without using additional plugins (which I would like to avoid)? For example, can another language appear according to user's language browser, or simply with a manual switcher?

Answer (score 0):

The shorts answer is no. The `__()` and `_e()` functions are evaluated on the server side. So by the time the page is sent tot the user, there is a plain string in the html. There is no way on the user end to access a different translation.

That said, you can get around this by using the [`locale` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/locale/). For instance, you could have a button on your site 'same page in french', add a query variable to the link, extract that on the server side, change the language and then generate the same page in a different language (its theme strings, not the actual post content).

Depending on how extensively you want to do this you're looking at quite some work of quite a lot of work. And you might come to regret that you didn't use that translation plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a plugin that works synergistically with the translations found in the Poedit files I've already created? Whether the answer is yes or no what do you suggest?
Unfortunately I do not know how to implement the solution in which you suggest me to create a query that extracts the language from the server because I am a neophyte. And still using this solution would involve having to click on a translation link every time you access a different page?

Comment: I have no direct experience with translation plugins, but they are meant to translate post content, not template files. So I wouldn't bet on them helping with your requirement.

Comment: Analyzing the problem I would practically need to translate both the texts of the posts and the "static" texts of the template files. 
Let's see if someone suggests something to me.